# Swapping objects with C++ and SDL 2.0

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm developing a game using C++ and SDL and have encountered a bug (in SDL or my code) that I simply can't figure out.
Basically I have a Bejewelled clone and I have a simple function to swap to pieces (not looking at restrictions now). What happens is that I'm able to swap this pieces only if the first one selected has greater X or Y than the second one, which translates into only being able to swap them up or left.
I've checked my code back and forth and even while debugging I can see that the swap is done correctly, but my second selected piece continues as selected and if I press outside the board or on a piece on the left or up, a new swap is registered.

My code is as follows

```
(...)
case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mCurrentSprite = BUTTON_SPRITE_MOUSE_DOWN;
            setPressed(true);
            gPressedButtons[pressedCount] = this;
            pressedCount++;
            if (pressedCount == 2)
            {
                swapSquares();
                pressedCount = 0;
                gPressedButtons[0]->setPressed(false);
                gPressedButtons[1]->setPressed(false);
            }
            break;
(...)
void swapSquares()
{
int tempType;
tempType = gPressedButtons[0]->getType();
gPressedButtons[0]->setType(gPressedButtons[1]->getType());
gPressedButtons[1]->setType(tempType);
if (tempType == gPressedButtons[1]->getType() || tempType1 == gPressedButtons[0]->getType())
{
    OutputDebugString(TEXT("swap done correctly\n"));
}
}
```

Then the pieces are rendered according to their type, hence why I swap them. Any idea what could be wrong with this? Why does it work in some cases and not in others?

Comment: How does it work with the event handling loop? Is gPressedButtons global or private method? Is that object method (I'm deducing this from `this` keyword) called from two different tiles/switchable simultanously?

Comment: I managed to solve it while fixing some other bugs, don't recall exactly how. but thanks for your help! :)